# How to configure Spring Security OAuth2 to verify my own JWT token and Google OpenID connection?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I currently have a microservices architecture secured by an authentication server and a resource server using Oauth2 protocol with my users stored in a database. To authenticate I use spring-security-oauth2 configured to return JWT tokens and these tokens travel in the request headers between my microservices.

Now I have a new requirement that I would like to be able to authenticate with Google using OpenID connect as well.

I have been researching how to do it but I haven't found a solution using spring-security-oauth2 because I want to keep my security core and avoid change it for this new requirement, this means I want to use my JWT certificate to validate the tokens that are flying between my microservices.

I suppose that I have to register the user with Google OpenId flow and use it to login with my current flow, but I don't know how to integrate with the web frontend, and how to register them.

I'm working with Spring Boot 1.5.4 and Spring Cloud 1.2.1

This is my current configuration:

**MyAuthorizationServer.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class MyAuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${keyStore.location}")
    private Resource resource;

    @Value("${keyStore.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${keyStore.alias}")
    private String alias;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory =
            new KeyStoreKeyFactory(resource, password.toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(alias));
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
          Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                 .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                 .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }
}
```

**MyResourceServer.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class MyResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DefaultTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/** ").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices);
    }
}
```

**MyWebServerSecurity.java**

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class MyWebServerSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Regards